# Problem in running ASP.NET Core 3.1 code in VS2019 16.9 with .NET Core 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I have web applications designed in .NET Core 3.1 and I have just updated my vs2019 to 16.9 version. Also I have installed .NET Core SDK 5.0

When I run my application now, it's not launching and throwing the following error in the Output:

```
The program '[23364] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

1. I tried the solution of deleting .vs folder but it did not work.
2. I do not want to upgrade to ASP.NET Core 5.0 as of now due to some business reasons.

Please help!

Comment: Not much we can help with just that little information.. did you try running using the .NET CLI? Try going to the project folder and run `dotnet run` and maybe there we see more interesting logs? Another approach you can take is use a global.json and set the SDK version there to 3.1 so the tooling (vs) will not use .NET 5.

Comment: The error comes from IIS Express, *not* your application. Your application is still running on .NET 3 unless you changed the target.

Comment: I used to have problem with IIS too, changing the IIS port in your launch settings may help. Also you can run and debug your app with just Kestrel without IIS.

Comment: Try the following steps: 1. open the Task Manager, and check if there has `iisexpress.exe` running, try to close them. 2. clear your application and rebuild the application, check if there have any error, then, running the application on IIS express. 3. Try to use Kestrel to debug your application first, then, re-use the IIS express again. 4. Perhaps when upgrade the VS2019, there has some issue, try to repair it.